# Get records from datatable grouped by date ( date interval)

Tags: c#, linq

I have a datatable whose columns are `name`, `code`, `dateAndTime`. Now I want to get the count of all the records for every hour in a Day using LINQ.

DateTime Column contains data as

```
2018-08-01 07:00:06.163
2018-08-01 07:50:11.873
2018-08-01 08:00:42.623
2018-08-01 07:20:48.363
2018-08-01 09:01:15.243
2018-08-01 06:01:16.507
```

Now I want to get the count of all the records from the start of the day to now (may be its 1 year or 6 month ).

Example would be:
if first record is around 5 Am on 2018-08-01 then its start with 2018-08-01 as first row

```
2018-08-01  7   - 36 count
2018-08-04  9   - 12 count
2018-08-07  11  - 12 count
2018-08-10  13  -  0 count
2018-08-13  15  - 36 count
```

i want only 12 row so time interval is divided 12 equal part may be its some day or month.

Comment: Have you tried something so far? What exactly was the problem?

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you are trying to group records based on hour.You can simply group by hour here.Suppose you have an employee class declared as:

```
 static List<Employee> employees = new List<Employee>
    {
        new Employee {FirstName = "Marc",date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1) },
        new Employee {FirstName = "John", date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(1) },
        new Employee {FirstName = "Robin",date = DateTime.Now.AddHours(2) },
        new Employee {FirstName = "Mike", date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(2) }
        };
```

Then you can group the records for every hour by grouping on hour.Following code may help you:

```
var emps = from employee in employees
                             group employee by employee.date.Hour into empGroup
                             select new
                             {
                                 key = empGroup.Key,
                                 items = empGroup
                             };

            foreach(var item in emps)
            {
                foreach(var groupItems in item.items)
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("group ");
                    Console.WriteLine("item={0} value={1} count={2}", item.key, groupItems.FirstName,item.items.Count());
                }

            }
```

Comment: no , its may be day or hour wise , depend on time interval .If there are one month data then this is day wise